# Maxscript - Changing the value for all Box objects in a Scene, on different Keyframes?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I am new to Maxcscript, I try to explain a problem the best I can,

I am trying to make a script in Maxscript, that would change a height to a zero of all box objects in a scene on their first keyframe.

I have several scenes that all have a  number of boxes, some have 12, some 20 boxes, etc.
And all boxes are animated  - but on different keyframes, for example first box is animated from 12-23rd frame, second box is animated from 30-45 frame, etc. (so I cant put specific frame number in a script)
Right now I am using this script to change a height of a box:

```
set animate on
modPanel.setCurrentObject $.baseObject
$.height = 0
```

using this script I have to manualy go to every boxs first keyframe and then execute the script.
So, Is there a way in Maxscript to make a script that would go to every box in a scene - go to their first keyframe, turn animate and change its height to a zero; from first to last box in a scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a beginner too.
but try this?

```
actionMan.executeAction 0 "40021"  -- Selection: Select All

for i in $ do
(
    if matchpattern i.name pattern: "*Box*" == true do --ObjectName matching part
    (
        local foo = i.height.track  --set Your Animation Controller
        slidertime = getkeytime foo 1

        set animate on
        i.height = 0
        set animate off
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. I also tried to use for cylinder objects too, but for some reason it won't work.
I only changed *Box* to *Cylinder*
I got this "no getkeytime function for undefined". Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: matchpattern i.name pattern: "*Box*"  change "*Cylinder*"

Comment: I can't english well:(

does Cylinder have animation keys?
getkeytime can works in Animation Controller.
You should to read an Animation Controllers in Autodesk MaxScript Help.

Comment: turns out that problem occurs only in some scenes, but in other it works OK. dont know why, I will try to find out and if I have some new info will post here.

Comment: `if classOf i == Box then ...` would be a better way to check if the object is a box (and the same idea for a cylinder), no need to keep the "Box" string in the name of the object.