# Maxscript - sliderTime to Keyframe?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I am a beginner, trying to make a script but I cant find an answer to this simple problem

I want to move animation slider to a time of first keyframe of a selected object

```
gettimerange $.pos.controller[1].controller
```

so, after I execute this line I got time interval (interval 29f 35f in this case) how to move animation slider using script, first to first keyframe, 
and then move animation slider to last keyframe(35f in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood well.
is it right?

```
foo = $.pos.controller[1].controller
bar = (foo.keys).count

slidertime = getkeytime foo bar --get Animation Controller's last key time
```

Comment: This script moves slider to last keyframe of animation of selected object.
I also need a command to go to first keyframe of selected object, do you maybe know how to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342140/maxscript-changing-the-value-for-all-box-objects-in-a-scene-on-different-keyf

Comment: slidertime = getkeytime foo 1 --get Animation Controller's first key time